# How to distinguish between server updates and user updates on a tableView?

Tags: javafx

I am trying to understand a behavior in *JavaFX* conceptually. I have a `TableView` which is backed by an `ObservableList`.

Now, when the server sends a update, this `ObservableList` will be updated either directly or via another `ObservableList`.

However, the same table can be updated by the user - say a particular `boolean` property column via an embedded `CheckBoxTableCell`.

On this update, without using a submit button, a call needs to go to the server automatically.

How to distinguish this user update from a server update, or there might be an infinite loop situation?

So, in the below code, if *list1* is the list from the server, it is bound to *list2* (which is used to tie to the `TableView`, which I have not shown here to avoid confusion).

Instead of binding, I can also use a listener to update *list2*, which I have also shown.

Now, if *list2* gets updated by the user on the UI by editing a `TableRow`, only then I want *list4* to be updated with the changes. I do not want *list4* to be updated when *list2* originally got updated from *list1*, which is from the server.

full code details:
MainApp

```
package com.personal.javafx1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
package com.personal.javafx1;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ObservableList<String> list1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList("one", "two", "three");
        ObservableList<String> list2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList("4");
        ObservableList<String> list4 = FXCollections.observableArrayList("5");
        //FilteredList<String> list2 = list1.filtered(p -> true);

        list1.addListener((ListChangeListener) c -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    //list2.addAll(c.getList());
                    System.out.println("items added to list 2 from list 1" + c);
                }
            }
        });

        list2.addListener((ListChangeListener) c -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    System.out.println("items added to list 1 from list 2" + c);
                }
            }
        });

        list1.addAll("add1", "add2");
        System.out.println("list1" + list1);
        System.out.println("list2" + list2);
        System.out.println("list4" + list4);


    }    
}
```

FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.personal.javafx1.FXMLController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please!

Comment: Added code as requested

Comment: The idea behind MRE is to allow people to copy and run your code. Since the code you posted apparently uses FXML, I believe it would be helpful if you also posted the contents of your `.fxml` file.

Comment: hi team, as requested, I have added the FXML, Main App and Controller code separately.

Answer (score 1):

The `ObservableList` objects you created do not trigger any of their listeners on the change of a property. `TableView` does not provide any functionality for modifying the content of the `items` list by itself, so you could add the communication to the server to the event handler modifying the list content. If a listener for the list is triggered for the change of a property of one of its elements, you may be able to intercept the change using `onEditCommit`. (Be aware that this requires you to set the property value yourself though, even if the property returned is a `WritableValue`.) This won't work for cell types that do not transition to the editing state such as `CheckBoxTableCell`.

For those kind of updates you could simply introduce a flag that you modify when doing updates based on server messages:

```
private boolean externalUpdate = false;

...
list.addListener((ListChangeListener) c -> {
    if (!externalUpdate) {
        // TODO: send update to server
    }
});

...

public void receiveServerUpdate(...) {
    externalUpdate = true;

    // TODO: modify list

    externalUpdate = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this method. LIke you rightly said, I want to capture updates due to CheckBoxTableCell and hence prefer just one method instead of other onEditCommit methods. I will try this out